# SQLServer - Determine whether a column is geometry or geography

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Is there a way to determine whether a column is "geometry" or "geography" in a Microsoft SQLServer database?

Ideally, I would like to do this programatically using Java/JDBC. I've tried using the java.sql.ResultSetMetaData but I get an incoherent response.

```
String className = rsmd.getColumnClassName(colID));
System.out.println(className);
```

Outputs:

```
"[B"
```

If there's no way to do it via JDBC/ResultSetMetaData, is there an SQL query I can use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get info for all columns from a special system table called INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS. Can add where statement for just the table (or columns) you want. Accessible like any other table.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Comment: I'm marking this as the correct answer. You can see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27305040/777443) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to get this info via the JDBC ResultSetMetaData class. At least not with the latest JDBC driver from Microsoft (sqljdbc_4.0.2206).

The only way to get this information currently is via a query. Example:

```
String sql = "SELECT DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS " +
"WHERE TABLE_NAME='" + tableName + "' AND COLUMN_NAME='" + columnName + "'";
```

I arrived at this conclusion by decompiling the **SQLServerResultSetMetaData.class**. The source for the `getColumnClassName()` method calls this:

```
this.rs.getColumn(paramInt).getTypeInfo().getSSType().getJDBCType().className();
```

The key method in this chain is `getSSType()` which returns an SSType. The SSType class contains mappings between data types in the database and JDBC data types. There is no mapping for "geometry" or "geography". IMHO this is a bug. Here's the source for SSType:

```
package com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc;

enum SSType
{
UNKNOWN(SSType.Category.UNKNOWN, "unknown", JDBCType.UNKNOWN), 
TINYINT(SSType.Category.NUMERIC, "tinyint", JDBCType.TINYINT), 
BIT(SSType.Category.NUMERIC, "bit", JDBCType.BIT),
SMALLINT(SSType.Category.NUMERIC, "smallint", JDBCType.SMALLINT),
INTEGER(SSType.Category.NUMERIC, "int", JDBCType.INTEGER), 
BIGINT(SSType.Category.NUMERIC, "bigint", JDBCType.BIGINT), 
FLOAT(SSType.Category.NUMERIC, "float", JDBCType.DOUBLE), 
REAL(SSType.Category.NUMERIC, "real", JDBCType.REAL), 
SMALLDATETIME(SSType.Category.DATETIME, "smalldatetime", JDBCType.TIMESTAMP),
DATETIME(SSType.Category.DATETIME, "datetime", JDBCType.TIMESTAMP), 
DATE(SSType.Category.DATE, "date", JDBCType.DATE), 
TIME(SSType.Category.TIME, "time", JDBCType.TIME), 
DATETIME2(SSType.Category.DATETIME2, "datetime2", JDBCType.TIMESTAMP), 
DATETIMEOFFSET(SSType.Category.DATETIMEOFFSET, "datetimeoffset", JDBCType.DATETIMEOFFSET), 
SMALLMONEY(SSType.Category.NUMERIC, "smallmoney", JDBCType.DECIMAL), 
MONEY(SSType.Category.NUMERIC, "money", JDBCType.DECIMAL), 
CHAR(SSType.Category.CHARACTER, "char", JDBCType.CHAR), 
VARCHAR(SSType.Category.CHARACTER, "varchar", JDBCType.VARCHAR), 
VARCHARMAX(SSType.Category.LONG_CHARACTER, "varchar", JDBCType.LONGVARCHAR), 
TEXT(SSType.Category.LONG_CHARACTER, "text", JDBCType.LONGVARCHAR), 
NCHAR(SSType.Category.NCHARACTER, "nchar", JDBCType.NCHAR), 
NVARCHAR(SSType.Category.NCHARACTER, "nvarchar", JDBCType.NVARCHAR), 
NVARCHARMAX(SSType.Category.LONG_NCHARACTER, "nvarchar", JDBCType.LONGNVARCHAR), 
NTEXT(SSType.Category.LONG_NCHARACTER, "ntext", JDBCType.LONGNVARCHAR), 
BINARY(SSType.Category.BINARY, "binary", JDBCType.BINARY), 
VARBINARY(SSType.Category.BINARY, "varbinary", JDBCType.VARBINARY), 
VARBINARYMAX(SSType.Category.LONG_BINARY, "varbinary", JDBCType.LONGVARBINARY), 
IMAGE(SSType.Category.LONG_BINARY, "image", JDBCType.LONGVARBINARY), 
DECIMAL(SSType.Category.NUMERIC, "decimal", JDBCType.DECIMAL), 
NUMERIC(SSType.Category.NUMERIC, "numeric", JDBCType.NUMERIC), 
GUID(SSType.Category.GUID, "uniqueidentifier", JDBCType.CHAR), 
SQL_VARIANT(SSType.Category.VARIANT, "sql_variant", JDBCType.VARCHAR), 
UDT(SSType.Category.UDT, "udt", JDBCType.VARBINARY), 
XML(SSType.Category.XML, "xml", JDBCType.LONGNVARCHAR), 
TIMESTAMP(SSType.Category.TIMESTAMP, "timestamp", JDBCType.BINARY);

final SSType.Category category;
private final String name;
private final JDBCType jdbcType;

private SSType(SSType.Category paramCategory, String paramString, JDBCType paramJDBCType)
{
this.category = paramCategory;
this.name = paramString;
this.jdbcType = paramJDBCType;
}

public String toString()
{
return this.name;
}

final JDBCType getJDBCType()
{
return this.jdbcType;
}

boolean convertsTo(JDBCType paramJDBCType)
{
return SSType.GetterConversion.converts(this, paramJDBCType);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at sys.columns. Join it with sys.types on system_type_id.